# AWS EMR - Saving Dataframe into hive external table on S3 - getting memory leak error

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, memory-leaks, emr

Hello i am writing spark using python and tring to write the dataframe into table and table is hive external and stored on AWS S3

below is the command : 
   sqlContext.sql(selectQuery).write.mode("overwrite").format(trgFormat).option("compression", trgCompression).save(trgDataFileBase)

Below is the error

ERROR ResourceLeakDetector: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel() See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.

spark sumit: 
spark-submit --master yarn --queue default --deploy-mode client --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 12g --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.debug.maxToStringFields=100 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table, say `trgDataFileBasetmp`, then using the same definition create the table on s3. You will need all the parameters in the definition like `SERDEPROPERTIES`, `TBLPROPERTIES`. Here the difference I have is `saveAsTable`:

```
sqlContext.sql(selectQuery).write.mode("overwrite").format(trgFormat).option("compression", trgCompression).saveAsTable(trgDataFileBase)
```

If this does not work then you can start with:

```
sqlContext.sql(selectQuery).write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(trgDataFileBase)
```